# django - Showing multiple child forms inside parent

Tags: django, forms, composite

I have been studying the modalforms & inline formsets but am not able to wrap my head around my composite objects, and want to see how things are done in django world -

I have this hierarchical model
**"Author"** has many **"Books"**
  Each **"Book"** has **4 Sections** -> Section-01, Section-02, Section-03 & Section-04
    Each **"Section"** has number of **attributes**.

I **want to show** all books on its own line
If a book is clicked, I'll expand a hidden DIV, which will show the 4 sections of that book.
Like so -
**Book-1 | Short Description of book (when clicked, shows the below section)

Section-01 | Section-02 | Section-04 | Section-04 |

Book-2 | Short Description of book (when clicked, shows the below section)

Section-01 | Section-02 | Section-04 |...

...

..

.**

I have all the HTML code figured out, using jquery to show/hide Divs.

**Question - I'm confused as to how I can pass all this data from the view to the HTML page and then render so that when user edits something, things are passed back, in the form of Forms.**

But is there a way to pass this whole composite object - Author+Books+AllSectionsInBook in one go.

Would be great if you could point me in a direction or how you solved this composition problem.
Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be great but unfortunately you would have to write it yourself. The brute force way of doing this is to have an author form, a formset of books, for each book a formset of sections. Then save the author form. Use that author id to save each of the books in the books formset, and finally use the book ids to save the sections in the sections formset.

I have often considered writing a recursive inline formset but it appears it would take a lot of thought to get right.

Comment: Wow.. that seems like reinventing the wheel.. I'll give passing json a try in that case, since I'm o.k. with bundle/unbundle with it.
But thanks a lot ! If I don't receive any other answers, I'll go with this. I was hoping there would be a simpler solution.